# It is possible to forcibly include IDE's directory (workspace) into Caching SSD?

Tags: solid-state-drive

I have Hybrid storage drive  (HDD 500 GB+ and **SSD 32 GB**). Can I forcibly include Eclipse IDE and Eclipse's work directory (Workspace) into SSD drive (which is used for caching by default)?

Answer (score 0):

No.  A hybrid drive works in a completely seamless fashion.  While you might know that it's a hybrid disk your computer does not.  There's nothing in the SATA spec to tell the hard drive what to store in the SSD cache.  It analogous to CPU cache.  It's there and it makes your computer faster, but the processor controls it, not the programmer.

Fortunately for you there's no need to force the hard drive to put those things into cache.  If you use them a lot they'll get cached automatically.  That's the beauty of a hybrid drive.